# Increment counter onclick

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have set the number X to 5. 
When clicking a button a script is run to update the database without refreshing - that works fine.
Now i want a number on the page to update to 6, also without the page refreshing.
I tried JS, but ended up having the number in an input field which looks bad. Is there any other way, maybe with jQuery.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Post code if you did

Comment: jQuery not needed. Define a container for the number like a `<span>` tag, and modify its contents with plain JavaScript via its innerHTML property.  `<span id='the-span>5</span> document.getElementById('the-span').innerHTML = 6;`

Comment: use `text()` function if you are using jQuery (http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use jQuery.

You can update everything on page by pure JavaScript, without jQuery.

Example from [Javascript Tutorial at tizag.com](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-innerHTML.php):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeText()
    {
    document.getElementById('boldStuff').innerHTML = 'Fred Flinstone';
    }
</script>

<p>
    Welcome to the site <b id='boldStuff'>dude</b>
</p> 

<input type='button' onclick='changeText()' value='Change Text'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will let you get the element by its id and update its value.

```
 document.getElementById('theId').innerHTML = newValue;
```

If you are not currently using jQuery then do not use it just for this.  If you are using jQuery you can do the following.

```
 $('#theId').html(newValue);
```

or

```
 $('#theId').text(newValue);
```

Depending on whether the newValue may or may not have html in it.

Both the jquery and straight javascript examples are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

with jquery `$("your containerselector").html(parseInt($("your containerselector").html()) + 1)` Though you need to be sure your container just contains on int.

Comment: Yes sure but in the end quite a lot of people end up using a javascript library as part of their website no?

Comment: Thats right @charly but we don't know is he already using jQuery or not. I assumed he is not, because he don't know how to use it. He should start learning from Javascript basics, not a framework.

Comment: True actually. That's might be one of the big problems on javascript. People start with a framework